# Is there any way to use ES6 normal exports like default exports?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
export function foo() {
  console.log('foo')
}

export function bar() {
  console.log('bar')
}
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
function foo() {
  console.log('foo')
}

function bar() {
  console.log('bar')
}

export foo
export bar
```

I know you can do something like this with a default export, but can it be done with normal exports?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for

```
export {foo, bar}
```

The [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-source-text-module-records) does a good job in listing all the possible ways to `import` and `export` something.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'll accept it as soon as I can. And thanks for the link.